# Leaflet Label Clickable

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I am trying to have `leaflet label` as a link or clickable. When click on `label` have to call a function, but cannot do that.

```
L.marker([lat,lng],{'icon':circlemarke}).bindLabel('Some thing as a message',{noHide:true});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your `Lable` as a `Link` this could be pretty simple, you just need to override this `CSS` style

```
.leaflet-label {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

and When you call your `bindLabel` function just add `<a>` tag like below

```
L.marker([lat,lng],{'icon':circlemarke})
.bindLabel('<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Some thing as a message</a>',{noHide:true});
```

and it'd work. Here is a link to working fiddle [Leaflet Lable as Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/6s10kt5t/)